# Same value assignment of multiple variables in a single statement

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Is there a way where I can assign the same value for different variables without constructing an array in a single statement?

For example, if I have variables *a,b,c,d*, and *e*, can I assign something like

```
a=b=c=d=e=10.0
```

?

I know that I can do in a single line:

```
a=10.0; b=10.0; c=10.0; d=10.0; e=10.0
```

But that is not I want since if I want to change the value 10.0 later to something else, I have to make the change everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come on Fortranners, you know you want to ...

```
equivalence(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Now all those rascals are going to have the same value at all times.

Comment: I assume they are only initialized to the same value.

Comment: This is the smartest answer that I got so far. However, as you said, this only works for initialization as it's a *declaration*, not a *statement*. :(

Comment: @hbaromega I would conclude that initialization is exactly *not* what `equivalence` is good for because the variables are *not* initialized this way, but instead they are stuck to the same memory down the road losing the ability to modify them individually anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The first version is not possible in Fortran. Following the (2008) Standard, an assignment is of the general form (ch. 7.2.1.1)

```
variable = expr
```

But why don't you try something like:

```
a=10.0; b=a; c=a; d=a; e=a
```

That way, you just need to change the value of `a` later on!

Comment: Another option to keep the code tidy, if the variables are always the same, a subroutine can be constructed such as change_variables(a,b,c,d,e,10.) that makes a, b, c, d, and e all equal to 10.

Comment: But if the variables are always the same, why use different variables? Another idea: what about pointers?

Comment: Perhaps the code is already written with a, b, etc. scattered around and it's not practical to change all the variables at this stage.

Comment: In my case, I need to initialize all the variables with the same value

Comment: Or at some point of the program I want to make all of them equal under a certain condition. So assigning `a=10.0` and then saying `b=a` has the same the same amount of pain of writing `a=10.0; b=10.0`. Pointer could be an alternative, but I suppose I cannot get rid of assignment for each variable.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
real, parameter :: NamedConst = 10.0

a=NamedConst; b=NamedConst; c=NamedConst; d=NamedConst; e=NamedConst
```

Then if you should use the special value `NamedConst` in more than one line, there is clearly a single place to change its value.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should consider to use an array instead of individual variables, especially if they serve similar purposes:

```
real :: myarray(5)

myarray(:) = 10.0
```