# How to replace all occurences of elements of a two dimensional array in do loops in fortran

Tags: arrays, replace, fortran, simultaneous

I've got stdin like that (elements are always > 10)

```
75 33 44 51
51 87 33 77
77 51 91 45
17 29 30 40
```

I would like to substitute 1 for one of the elements in each row (randomly - according to a random 1 =< n =< 4) and 0 for the others in the row, but so as to change equal elements throughout, i.e., 51 in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd rows, 33 in in the 1st and 2nd rows, and 77 in the 2nd and 3rd rows but so that I don't get two 1s in a row. Assuming that n=4 for the 1st and 2nd row, and n=3 for the 3rd and 4th one, I should end up with

```
0  0  0  1
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
```

which is different from just putting n's in, i.e., I don't want

```
0  0  0  1
0  0  0  1
0  0  1  0
0  0  1  0
```

What I actually want is to change all occurrences of equal elements according to the values of their elements throughout. E.g., replacement 51 -> 1 should change 51 in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd row to 1 as soon as 51 in the 1st row is changed to 1, but not their names. Their names c(i,j) in the array should, however, respond with their new value when called. Then, random n's should be overruled by already existing 0's and 1's in each next row, but should stay when a row is not so affected via links to the previous rows as the 4th row.

I didn't put in any Fortran specifics because I want to avoid the discussion being led astray. Constructive suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you need to read about the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: I wonder whether this is an *xy problem* ?  What are you trying to achieve ?  I can just about understand what your sort-of-code does, but not what end it is supposed to deliver.  FWIW I agree with @evets that your existing code could more easily be achieved by using a `where` construct, or constructs.

Comment: Another vote for where being a likely solution, but as I can't really follow what you are doing I can't say for certain

Comment: As your compiler says, `c(i,j)=c(k,l)=1` isn't [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23654753/3157076).

Comment: When you write `c(4,1) (51)` do you mean that the value in column `4` row `1` of the array `c` is `51` ?  If you do, you are at odds with how Fortran indexes arrays, where `c(4,1)` refers to the 1st element of the 4th row.  In the original version of `c` the value `51` is at `(1,4)` and `(2,1)` as Fortran sees it.

Comment: Constructive suggestion.   This question should be deleted as you have deleted all your comments and your attempt at writing a Fortran solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about the `WHERE` construct.  If I understand your description, this toy program should work for you.

```
program foo

 implicit none

 integer c(3,4), i, n
 real u

 c = transpose(reshape([75,33,44,51,51,87,33,77,77,51,91,45],[4,3]))

 call prn  ! Print original matrix

 do i = 1, 3
    call random_number(u)
    n = 1 + floor(4*u)
    print '(A,I0)', 'n = ', n
    where(c(i,:) /= c(i,n)) c(i,:) = 0
    where(c == c(i,n)) c = 1
    call prn  ! Print altered matrix
 end do

 contains

   subroutine prn
      integer i
      do i = 1, 3
         write(*,'(4(I0,1X))') c(i,:)
      end do
      print *
   end subroutine prn
end program foo
```

Comment: You need to study the example code I gave you.  It is showing you how to mask the array with `WHERE`.  Your poorly formatted example code and poor description (as others have also found) make it difficult to actually give you a complete example. You can work out the details.  If you want to start with c(4,1), then get rid to of the use of random_number() to generate a location in a row to  build the mask and build your method to build the mask.

Comment: I just realized you don't undestand Fortran array indexing!  Your array does not have an element `C(4,1)'.

Comment: What is your declaration for `c`?  Is it `integer c(3,4)` or `integer c(4,3)`?  Add -fcheck-=all to your command line.

Comment: So, 4 rows and 3 column.

Comment: You don't know Fortran, do you?   Fortran is a column major language.  `allocate(c(ncol,nrow))` gives you `ncol` rows and `nrow` columns.